# Upgrade Azure durable functions from 1.6.2 to 1.7.0 Nodejs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have written some durable functions using version 1.6.2 . The new [1.7.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/releases) is now out. I want to upgrade.

Will just doing 
`func extensions install -p Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask -v 1.7.0` do the job? or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to do anything else except upgrading the extension. [1.7.0 release](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/releases/tag/v1.7.0) doesn't change existing APIs but adds new features and fixes bugs, so our code depending on 1.6.2 extension will not break.

As for the new features, some of them are related to [DurableOrchestrationClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management) which is not implemented in current JS SDK, so we can't benefit from them unless SDK is upgraded. We can try others like [call built-in HTTP API for starting new orchestration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/61), e.g locally call `http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/orchestrators/{functionName}` to strat new orchestrator instead of using Http trigger as a starter.

About Durable Functions commands in Azure Functions Core Tools, the new release of Cli has not been pushed to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools) so we can't update it as well.

Comment: will just doing `func extensions install -p Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask -v 1.7.0` upgrade the extension?

Comment: @NafisIslam Sure, extensions are c# nuget packages which are similar to node packages we installed through npm and function runtime will load the new extension automatically, no more step is required. Or you can edit its version in `extensions.csproj`, VSCode will restore it for us as well.

Comment: hi @JerryLiu, what do you mean exactly with "function runtime will load the new extension automatically, no more step is requied" ? (when and how ?). I'm asking since the docs are pretty confusing. It is not clear 1) if the extension bundle in host.json is only used for local development 2) if extensions.csproj is ignored when using the bundle both locally and when deploying